# Remaking the Stack Overflow logo

Tags: tex-core

I want to build the Stack Overflow logo, but not just the stack, also the text.

If it looks like this:

[image: Stack Overflow Logo]

How do I recreate it using TeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I would recommend something like [the solution presented here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301724/how-to-draw-the-stack-overflow-icon-with-tikz/301725), at least to start creating it

Comment: It would be easier to [download it](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/logo/) (from the official source) in [SVG format](https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg) and then convert it to PDF for inclusion as an image.

Comment: it's usually better to simply use the supplied image for a company logo, approximating it is unlikely to be as good and may be a trademark violation.